# Django modelform - when errors in the form it is showing excluded fields and losing translations?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Im seeing a weird behaviour with my modelform. If I submit and a field has errors, when I re display it with the errors, excluded fields are appearing. Also its happening that the fields were translated into spanish and I m getting the labels in the original English.

I m using django 1.6.10, does anyone know if this is a bug or I m doing something wrong?

I'm not doing anything fancy with the rendering, I'm just doing `{{ form }}` in the template.

For instance this is a normal form

[image]

But if I submit the field empty I get the extra excluded field "notes" and the original field's name in English "plate number":

[image]

Here is the model code:

```
class Operation3Domain(models.Model):
    operation    = models.ForeignKey(Operation, unique=True)
    date         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_date  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    notes        = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    #this one is the only one I want to show:
    plate_number = NumberPlateField()
    class Meta:
        app_label = "operation"
```

and the model form:

```
class Operation3DomainForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = Operation3Domain
        labels  = { 'plate_number': 'Dominio/Patente'}
        exclude = ['operation', 'notes']
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by 'excluded fields'?

Comment: the ones I define in exclude in the Meta of the form

Comment: Could you post your models code? There a few possibilities why this may happen.

Comment: Ok I found the answer, it was in the creation of the form. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question!

So the problem to excluded fields was that in the creation of the form I had an outdated exclude parameter (sorry!), which is overriding the form's exclude.

```
form_class = modelform_factory(step_model, exclude=('operation',))
form = form_class(request.POST, instance=instance)
```

BUT! I still don't know why the form appears in English instead of spanish, which doesn't happen if I use the form class directly:

```
form = Operation3DomainForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
```

Thanks!